# Cell borders vary between browsers

Tags: css, html-table, border

I have one problem with borders it TD tags. I have no idea why Firefox don't display borders and Google Chrome displays.

Look at this: http://mirgorod.us/sandbox/labirint/

Problem solved.

td must have `&nbsp;`

Comment: You should post the problematic code here rather than offering a link to some website.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at your website, you should put 
`&nbsp;` in the td to see the border. By keeping the cells empty, Firefox doesnt display borders.